# How to remove decimals in Looker

Tags: decimal, looker-studio

I'm doing a report in Looker. It is connected to a google sheet (data source). There's a column for age and the data type is numeric, however is displays the age a table I created in Looker with decimals. How can I fix it[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a new calculated field using [ROUND()](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7583305?hl=en&ref_topic=7583517)

```
ROUND(Age,0)
```

- 

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove decimal points in this way.

### using `round()`

- Generating a new field and using round()
- Also removes an old field and uses a custom-generated field

Comment: This seems to be the same as the solution already proposed in the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75230795)...